# Product image is not shown in View Mode Node:Product List

Tags: views, commerce, nodes

I'm starting with Commerce Kickstart 2 together with demo store.

I added a product and upload one image, this product has one of the demo store variation types (Bags & Cases) and the product display type associated.

It seems simple since I didn't change nothing. But when I click in main menu the products already there are listed fine, with product image, only my new product don't show the image.

I see in variation types Bags & Cases that the *Images field*, Column *Format*, is defined as *image delta*, Image style: **product_medium**. And that is the point. In MySite/sites/default/files/styles directory are the styles of images. In that directory there is the product_medium directory where the images showed when in *View Mode Node:Product list* (the list of bags listed when click in *To carry*).

Well, the fact is when I create the product there is no option to load an image that will saved in MySite/sites/default/files/styles/product_medium directory. And that's the problem. Since when I manually copy the image to that directory, the image is showed up.

Where I define this product_medium image?

Comment: Could it be that your file folders are not setup correctly? Checkout https://www.drupal.org/node/15368 Also check your database log if there are any file related errors reported, more info at https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/dblog

Comment: Oh my. That's it. Drupal couldn't right in sites/default/files/styles because hadn't permission to do it. I gave right permissions and now it's ok. Thanks @PontusNilsson.

Comment: @PontusNilsson, You could put your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that your file folders are not setup correctly? Checkout drupal.org/node/15368 Also check your database log if there are any file related errors reported, more info at drupal.org/documentation/modules/dblog